# How to clear BIOS-related info on screen then print message?

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, interrupt, low-level

everyone! I'm sharpening my assembly low-level skills and made myself a simple bootloader. I now made some routines and the entrypoint and successfully output a message however, I want to clear the screen so in outputting my message, it comes out clean. I've tried making a routine which clears the `AX` register,  stores the content of address `0xb800` to `BX` then copying or `MOV`ing the contents of the `AX` register.
like this:

```
vram equ 0xb800

xor ax, ax
mov bx, [vram]
mov bx, ax
int 10h
```

it successfully clears the screen but I have a problem, as shown on the picture, it stretches the text.
[image: stretched output]

---

Then I searched for some answers. I didn't found some answers because search results just gives me DOS interrupts to clear the screen.

But, I did try using `INT 10, AH=07h` but I don't how to use it.

please lend me a hand thank you! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text gets 'stretched' because you setup for a 40-columns screen! You've written:

> ```
> xor ax, ax    <<<< This is video mode 0, so 40x25 16-color text
> int 10h
> ```

Use

```
mov  0003h
int  10h
```

to setup the 80x25 16-color text screen.

---

> ```
> vram equ 0xb800
>
> xor ax, ax
> mov bx, [vram]
> mov bx, ax
> int 10h
> ```

In the above code you seem to have mixed 2 ways to clear the screen.

### Setting the video mode

BIOS offers a number of video modes. Some are text modes, others are graphics modes. In a graphics mode you can address every single pixel whereas in a text mode you deal with colored characters. Of course, in the graphics modes you can output colored characters too.
This is a list of the more relevant modes:

```
01h 40x25 16-color text          25 rows, 40 columns -> wide characters!
03h 80x25 16-color text          25 rows, 80 columns
07h 80x25 monochrome text        25 rows, 80 columns
10h 640x350 16-color graphics    25 rows, 80 columns
12h 640x480 16-color graphics    30 rows, 80 columns
13h 320x200 256-color graphics   25 rows, 40 columns -> wide characters!
```

### Clearing the video memory manually

Your equate `vram equ 0xb800` represents the segment in memory where the regen buffer is located. The value 0xB800 needs to be loaded in a segment register. Next code will clear (the 1st page of) the 80x25 text screen:

```
mov  ax, vram
mov  es, ax
xor  di, di
mov  cx, 80 * 25
mov  ax, 0720h      ; WhiteOnBlack space character
cld
rep stosw
```

### Clearing the video memory using BIOS

BIOS provides 2 functions that can scroll a window in the active page, which is most of the time DisplayPage 0. Next code uses function 07h to clear (the entire active page of) the 80x25 text screen:

```
mov  dx, 184Fh    ; (79,24) Lowerright corner
xor  cx, cx       ; (0,0) Upperleft corner
mov  bh, 07h      ; WhiteOnBlack
mov  ax, 0700h    ; BIOS.ScrollWindowDown, AL=0 ClearWindow
int  10h
```

Comment: @FryingRonald http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0069.htm

Comment: @FryingRonald I have included additional video modes in my answer, plus more ways to clear the screen.